# Roles and responsibilities in Devops

Tags: devops

In a Devops context, Who is the responsible for the automation tasks ?
more exactly in the case of "pipeline as a code" in jenkins . who is supposed to do this task ? the devoloper or the operator ?
who is the actor ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

"The key to DevOps is greater collaboration between engineering and operations."

Roles : [DEVOPS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gM93I.jpg)

Responsibilities :
1.  Management : The DevOps Engineer ensures compliance to standards by monitoring the enterprise software and online websites. The engineer also regulates tools and processes in the engineering department and catalyses their simultaneous enhancement and evolution. 
2   Design and Development : Design and Development of enterprise infrastructure and its architecture is one of the major responsibilities that DevOps Engineers are tasked with.  Such Engineers are highly skilled coders which enable them to script tools aimed at enhancing developer productivity.
3   Collaboration and Support : The DevOps’ Modus Operandi is to collaborate extensively and yield results in all aspects of their work. Everything ranging from technical analyses to deployment and monitoring is handled, with the focus to enhance overall system reliability and scalability. The diagram below gives one a clear picture of the values that define DevOps.
4    Knowledge : DevOps staff and Engineers aid in promotion of knowledge sharing and overall DevOps culture throughout the engineering department
5   Versatile Duties : DevOps staff and Engineers also take on work delegated by IT director, CTO, DevOps head and more. They will also perform similar duties to the designations mentioned above.

Answer (score 1):

**Standard Definition** :

DevOps is an IT mindset that encourages communication, collaboration, integration and automation among software developers and IT operations in order to improve the speed and quality of delivering software.

**Layman's Definition** :

Any kind of automation that enables the opportunity for smoother Development, Operations, Support and delivery of the product is DevOps.

**Indrustry's View** :

There usually are two prominent area's where DevOps mindset is applied across industry :

a) Primary functionaries of DevOps like

```
• Continuous Integration, 
• Continuous Delivery, 
• Continuous Deployment, 
• Infrastructure as an code or infrastructure Automation,
• CI/CD Pipeline Orchestration, 
• Configuration Management and 
• Cloud Management (AWS, Azure or GCP)
```

b) Secondary functionaries of DevOps like

```
• SCM tool Support, 
• Code Quality tech support like Sonar, Veracode, Nexus etc. 
• Middleware tech support for tools like NPM, Kafka, Redis, NGIMX, API Gateway, etc 
• Infrastructure tech support for components like F5, DNS, Web Servers, Build Server Management etc
• OS Level support for miscellaneous activities lke Server Patching, Scripting for automation of server level tasks etc.
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no exact answer to this. It depends on many factors.

The development team will most likely want more ownership over the pipeline, and therefore would want to own the templates / code required to achieve the end goal of automation.

The opposite side of this is also completely valid. An operations team could be the custodians of a pipeline and mandate a development team must meet certain standards and use their automation pipelines to be able to get into an environment or onto a platform.

If an environment is an island, and development teams are trying to get to that island. Each development team can build their own bridge to get there. Or the operations team can build a bridge and ask the development teams to use it. Both are valid and the end result is the same either way.

If the end result is the same, then the only thing that matters is how you apply it in the context of the organization, team(s) and the people you are working with to achieve that common goal.

Answer (score 0):

The assigned developer (and scrum team) should be responsible for the complete delivery of all aspects of development through final deployment into production. This fosters the notions of ownership and empowerment, and focuses responsibility for the full life cycle delivery of the service (application).

DevOps engineering should be responsible for providing an optimal tool chain and environments for rapid and quality delivery. I see DevOps role as the development focused precedent to SRE. If SRE's maintain high performance, stable production environments, then DevOps team maintains optimal development and testing environments. In theory, DevOps should extend into the realm of SRE, conforming into a single team supporting the environments for rapid innovation with quality to meet the business needs.

Answer (score 0):

Everything from committing of the code to production. This includes

- Automation
- Production Support
- Writing automation scripts
- Debugging Production Infrastructure

In short Devops = Infrastructure + Automation + Support